# How to customize Touch Bar on the Macbook Pro 13" when Mathematica is on

Tags: macbook-pro, touch-bar

Whenever I use Wolfram Mathematica, the Touch Bar on my Macbook Pro has a "New Document" button. My question is, how do I make sure I don't have that button when I open Mathematica?

It is annoying, as every time I reach to hit the `esc` key, sometimes the "New Document" button gets tapped, resulting in a new document popping up.

Thanks for any advice you have!

Comment: Yes it is very annoying indeed!

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. If the app supports it, you can go in View > Customise Touch Bar ([more info here provided by Apple](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/customize-the-touch-bar-mchl5a63b060/mac))
2. You can install [BetterTouchTool](https://www.folivora.ai), which is very powerful, and has (among other things) the ability to fully customise the TouchBar per app, globally, add scripts or anything really ([other alternatives here](https://www.digitaltrends.com/computing/best-touch-bar-apps-for-macbook-pro/))